# Локальная сеть коммутатор и роутер

Tags: роутер, коммутатор

Ситуация такая, что есть коммутатор (неуправляемый) и роутер tp link самый простой. Как настроить чтобы все пользователи были в одной сети. К коммутатору подключены 4 пользователя на прямую. Роутер подключен к коммутатору и на роутере 3 пользователя. Надо сделать так чтобы 4 и 3 пользователя были в одной сети и видели друг друга. Схему [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Они и есть в одной сети. Если на компах адреса статические - настройте их все в одну подсеть.

Comment: у 4 пользователей которые на коммутаторе своя локальная сеть у 3 пользователей которые на роутере своя локальная сеть. А надо чтоб была общая локальная сеть у них. Я сам чайник в этом

Comment: Ну так выньте из входящего, засуньте во внутренний вход.

Comment: И три компа, и коммутатор должны быть подключены к LAN-разъёмам роутера.

Comment: Все получилось. Где вы были раньше))))

Comment: локальная сеть работает, а интернет перестал работать? в этом случае что можно сделать? я как понимаю идет конфликт коммутатора и роутера